# Illustrator: where is the non-breaking space?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, typesetting, white-space

I'm using the last version of Illustrator (2021: 25.0.1) on a mac (Catalina).

Usually, to insert a non-breaking space, I would go to "Type" and then "Space" or "Special characters" and find the non-breaking space.

But in this new version, it's impossible to find it again.

I'm trying to add a non-breaking space between the word and the French quotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Illustrator is not very good with these advanced typo things, but if you really must, try to:

- Select your text which is supposed to not break
- Open the Character Panel
- Open the flyout menu, on the top right corner
- Click `No Break`

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Well in French it is written "sans retour automatique" which means "without automatic return". The mention is not very evocative, but it works.